# Writing "$B$ is the number of elements in set $A$ that are less than $0$" in symbols

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let

$$A = \{0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0\}$$

and let $B$  be the number of elements in $A$ that are less than $0$. Is it correct if I write it like this?

$$B = |\{A\}| < 0$$

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

You could write:

> $$B=\left\vert\{\;x\in A \;|\; x < 0\;\}\right\vert$$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why the $\vert \vert$? What do they signify? "The number of elements in", i.e. "length of"?

Comment: It is the same thing you used, it stands for the cardinality of the set here.

Comment: Thanks (but I'm not OP) :)

Comment: Many thanks! :)